# Django capture agent's computer device info

Tags: python, django

In my web application, I want to capture complete info of agent's computer device and if user logs in my web application on a different device, system will trigger some function.

I have already checked **django-user-agents** but it is not giving complete info, for ex. a user can have same browser(version) and same os family and version on two different computers. In this case my application will not be able to identify whether the user is using same computer device or different.

Comment: Basically, you can't.  Or at least not reliably ... which I presume is a requirement for you.  Even the client IP address that you get in the HTTP request information may not be the IP of the user's actual machine.  (For various reasons ...)  And information about the user's hardware will not be available to you for security and privacy reasons.

Comment: If you Google for "get users hardware information in web application" ... you will find **OLD** suggestions that involve technologies like Silverlight, Flash, Java applets that purportedly can get you device information.  But these are all deprecated technologies, and any security aware user will have uninstalled or disabled them.